# Developing a Hindi TTS engine in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I wanted to know how can I make a Engine to support Hindi for Text-To -Speech for Android.
I don't want to use any paid Engine version nor I want to have a web-service kind of interface providing the transliteration. I wanted to build an actual Hindi Support TTS Engine. How can I start? What are the steps.

Thanks,